# How does Newey West affect inference?

Tags: regression, linear-model, neweywest

I understand that the [Newey-West estimator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newey%E2%80%93West_estimator) is an approach to estimate the covariance of the linear regression estimator (OLS) when there are heteroskedasticity and autocorrelation. Should it modify the estimator itself though? In other words, if $$\hat\beta_{\text{OLS}}=\left(X^\prime X\right)^{-1} X^\prime y,$$ then what should $\hat\beta_{\text{NW}}$  be?

Comment: The point estimator itself remains unaffected, NW is about, as you say, using another covariance estimator.